# Flexbox and Position Absolute Without Top/Bottom in Chome vs. FF & IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, flexbox

I've discovered a difference in flexbox implementation between Chrome and Firefox/Safari. When you have a position absolute element that has no top/bottom/left/right set, in Chrome the element snaps to top: 0, left: 0, while in the other browsers the top and left values are the same as if the element was statically positioned.

[Take a look at the codepen here.](http://codepen.io/alflenniken/pen/mAwOXE)

**What is the recommendation of the flexbox spec for this situation? Which browser or browsers are demonstrating buggy behavior?**

HTML

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="offset">Offset</div>
  <div class="absolute">Absolute</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 8px;
}
.offset {
  width: 300px;
  height: 96px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 96px;
}
```

Comment: Had a look at the specs, the expected behavior is clearly outlined by the W3C.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, `justify-content: space-between;` is not involved at all.

Comment: @TylerY86, read what it says: **This question already has an answer here:** It's not about the question, it's about the answer.

Comment: I read the answer. I don't see what `justify-content: space-between` has to do with this, or what `position: absolute` has to do with the other one.

Comment: Your answer doesn't say anything about the W3C spec. Eh whatever.

Comment: @TylerY86, in Firefox, an absolutely positioned flex item is *not* removed from the normal flow. That's why the red box doesn't cover the offset like in Chrome. In Firefox, an absolutely-positioned flex item is considered an *in-flow* sibling. My answer explains this in more detail in the dupe. It's not a W3C spec issue. It's more of a bug with Firefox.

Comment: @Michael_B The W3C specifically covers the behavior of absolutely positioned children of flex containers (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items), and current tests show that Firefox is conformant (https://test.csswg.org/harness/results/css-flexbox-1_dev/grouped/section/4.1/), however that is not the case. The tests do not cover these scenarios appropriately.

Comment: @TylerY86, you can tell from this question alone that not all browsers conform to the spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a difference in layout between Blink and WebKit.

I think the current recommendation would be to either specify the `top` and `left`, or use something that has better behavior.

[Is nesting the div an acceptable alternative for the current issue?](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrwEaQ)

[I think Blink (Chrome) is technically correct here.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)
Absolutely positioned children should not participate in the flex box layout model.
They should be treated as the starting item in the element.

*Edit: They may need to update their [test cases](https://test.csswg.org/harness/test/css-flexbox-1_dev/section/4.1/) - they need to separate Blink and WebKit, and they need this particular overlap test.*